# Exchanging data between Visual C++ and Python

Tags: c++, python, controls, pipe

Here's the story,

I have a Visual C++ code that runs a vehicle simulator. The simulator capture's the vehicle's state in a vector form, and can receive control inputs (eg. steering angle, pedal) either from the keyboard or manually (through code). My objective is to automate vehicle control, however, I have implemented the control class in Python.

I want to input the state of the vehicle from the C++ code to the python class, in which some processing is done. Then, the python class should output the corresponding control input, to be received by the C++ code.

Is there an easy way to achieve this? I have read similar posts but none of them was clear for me.

One way I thought about is using files, both classes read and write to a file from which they get the vehicle state and the control input, however, this could have tedious synchronization problems!

Pipelining is also feasible, but seems very complex, unless you could provide a nice simple solution :) :)

The bottomline is that, I want the C++ class and the python class to run concurrently while exchanging data between each other.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to run the two programs concurrently then there is no easy way to do it, and you will have to implement an asynchronous communication mechanism between the 2 separate processes.

One way to achieve this is to use sockets. That way your controller and C++ application could run on different machines if the need arises.

On the C++ side you could base you application around `boost::asio`  to read messages from the Python control application and send responses. see: [Boost Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html)

For the python side see: [Python sockets HowTo](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html)

Notes:

`boost::python` will allow you to call C++ from Python and Python from C++.

`SWIG` can also be used to wrap C++ classes so that they can be called from Python.

Comment: Hi mark, thanks, you seem to be closing up on the answer, my two programs (C++ and the python) are both in the same machine, is there an easy way to create asynchronous communication? You mentioned sockets but that might be more complex since its for programs residing in different machines.

Comment: The two programs will be running as separate processes, each having their own address space. That means you are limited to standard interprocess communication mechanisms ( pipes, sockets, shared memory etc.). I believe that using sockets is the most flexible option because it would allow you to run each application of different machines in the future. There is also a large amount of information on how to do this with both Python and C++, ergo I believe this is also the easiest method.

Comment: Thanks a lot mark! Guess it's time to learn about implementing sockets :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Boost::Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/python/doc/index.html) to wrap your C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try `ctypes` for that ([see here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html))?

To call things in python from C++, you can use the [Python API](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/intro.html).

Comment: Hi xgbi, I don't want to call functions from C++. Rather, I want the C++ class and the Python class to run concurrently while data is exchanged between them. Such that the C++ code is the simulator, and the Python class is an agent!

Comment: Then you'll have to provide somewhere an interface. If it is not too hard I'd suggest some form of REST interface. There are plenty of micro http servers in C++ that will allow you to do that. Otherwise, you can dig in [Google's Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/).